# How to get values from API?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I apologize for this post because it may seem banal to some people. But I would like to understand the operation of the **GET API**, unfortunately, somehow I have not found an accessible tutorial. As the best way to learn from examples, could anyone show me how to get the values from the name tag in the easiest way? can be up to textBox.

In xml:

https://bdl.stat.gov.pl/api/v1/subjects?lang=pl&format=xml

In json:

https://bdl.stat.gov.pl/api/v1/subjects?lang=pl&format=json

Code

```
public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool hasVariables { get; set; }
    public List<string> children { get; set; }
    public string levels { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
         var json = wc.DownloadString("https://bdl.stat.gov.pl/api/v1/subjects?lang=pl&format=json");

        Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);

        richTextBox1.Text = result.name;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Search the web for "C# parse JSON" or "C# parse XML" and show an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: I have added code to the original post, for future reference please understand how to ask a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The best way to learn is to look at examples of calling Web API's with `WebClient` or HttpClient`, then look at examples of deserialization to turn your JSON string from a string to an object representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing various classes in order to get your JSON string Deserialized properly. Try like:

```
    public class Results
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool hasVariables { get; set; }
        public List<string> children { get; set; }
        public string levels { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public string first { get; set; }
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
        public string last { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonObject
    {
        public int totalRecords { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int pageSize { get; set; }
        public Links links { get; set; }
        public List<Results> results { get; set; }
    }
```

And then use like:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
   var json = wc.DownloadString("https://bdl.stat.gov.pl/api/v1/subjects?lang=pl&format=json");
  JsonObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject>(json);
  foreach (var res in result.results)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(res.name);
  }
}
```